# How can I pin a folder to the Windows 7 taskbar with a custom icon?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

The Windows 7 taskbar pins normal applications easily enough; but pinned folders are rolled up under generic instance of explorer.exe and generic folder icon.

***Is there anyway to have folder pinned to the taskbar with a custom icon?***

Not as a shortcut but as a pinned item (i.e. running instance uses same icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, copy the folder path you which you want. (with two quotation marks " ") for example:

> "C:\Users\AmirrezA"

You can also do that by right clicking on the folder and selecting "Copy as Path".

In the second step, right click on your desktop and point to `New` then create a `Shortcut`. A window will appear which have a single text-box. in that box, type "`explorer.exe`" without quotation marks. Then add a space and then paste the path you copied in the first step. so the text-box will be something like this:

> explorer.exe "C:\Users\AmirrezA"

Just note that there is a space between `exe` and `"`. then click on Next where you should enter a name for your shortcut finally click on Finish.
You'll see an item on the desktop. right click on that and select properties. In `Shortcut` tab, click on `Change Icon` then select the icon you want or load that by clicking on `Browse...` then save the settings and close the window.

Finally, right click on that Item again and select `Pin to Taskbar`. Now, it's done!

Comment: Excellent. And it doesn't roll up under normal pinned explorer windows either :-)

Comment: Yep, that's right. and of course sorry, I don't speak English well so you or other members should edit the answer as much as you and they can.